# Xamarin.Forms Android Archive fails because of missing MDBS-File

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I developed my first Xamarin.Forms App, and it built fine, runs on all my machines and emulators, but when I try to archive the Android App into an APK, the archive process fails.

[image: The Error I get when I try to Archive the App]

Translation:
"The Archive File could not be generated, because there was a Error while copying MDBS-Files.
A part of the Path "C:\Users...Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources.dll" could not be found.
I added the Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources Nuget and all it's dependencys to my project. But it still doesn't work.

What is causing this error?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13520

Comment: This worked for me! I searched for almost a week for a answer and didn't find this post. Could you post this as answer, so i can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a known bug in Xamarin: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13520

Answer (score 16):

A workaround.

Create a folder somewhere in `C:` where it is not very deep in folder structure.

Go to VS -> Tools -> Options

[image]

Then set
[image]

retry Archive

[image]

And you should be good.

Comment: In my case my project name was long and I had to set that path as C:\a in order to make it work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My issue was because the Archive path was too long. Go to "Tools > Options > Android Settings" and set to a shorter path (not too deep) solve the problem. There is a path limitation in Windows.